# Custom Attribute - Set Attribute Usage for Only Private Members

Tags: c#, attributes, private-members, attributeusage

I creating a **custom attribute** and I would like to the set the `AttributeUsage` (or maybe some other attribute in the attribute class) so that I my attribute **can only be used in private methods**, is that possible?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the reasons for private-only attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature available in `C# (as of 4.0)` that allows you to restrict `attribute` usage based on a member's accessibility.

The question would be why do you want to do that?

Because given below attribute,

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class MethodTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MethodTestAttribute()
    { }
}
```

and below class,

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MethodTest]
    private void PrivateMethod()
    { }

    [MethodTest]
    protected void ProtectedMethod()
    { }

    [MethodTest]
    public void PublicMethod()
    { }
}
```

You can easily get attributes of private methods using following code:

```
var attributes = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods().
                 Where(m => m.IsPrivate).
                 SelectMany(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MethodTestAttribute), false));
```